# User input as starting time

Tags: c++, timing

Ok so im working on a timing program for long races in skiing and what not. I want to be able to have user input the starting time of race but I haven't found a good way to do that. Im using

```
struct tm * now = localtime( & maali );
```

to get current time (finish time) and difftime to calculate the difference.
Finishing time is in 2013-12-21-16-32-00 format.

Edit:
Ok ill elaborate a bit. I want the user to type the starting time in for example YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS format, which I could then use for calculations.

Edit 2.0

```
printf ("Enter year: "); scanf ("%d",&year);
printf ("Enter month: "); scanf ("%d",&month);
printf ("Enter day: "); scanf ("%d",&day);
printf ("Enter hour: "); scanf ("%d", &hour);
printf ("Enter minute: "); scanf ("%d", &minute);
printf ("Enter second: "); scanf ("%d", &second);
```

Thats where im at with getting the time. Getting that to a time_t is the problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I do not see exactly what the question is.

Comment: He wants to convert user input to time_t format and enter it into time_t variable -My guess .

Comment: ^That's exactly what i want :)

Comment: I guess this will help you http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data you got from the  user in `tm struct`

And call function mktime

`time_t mktime (struct tm * timeptr);`

Here is an example how to use those functions -

[example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)